# Como posso converter PNG pra JPG em C#?

Tags: c#, imagem, conversão

Estou trabalhando num projeto antigo que usa ASP Site.

Preciso converter imagem de PNG pra JPG.

Como fazer isso?

**Nota**: Não quero renomear o arquivo, quero transformar o mime de `image/png` para `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Downvoter, alguma sugestão de melhoria?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma solução é abrir a imagem e depois salvar como JPG

```
Image png = Image.FromFile(@"C:\caminho-da-imagem.png");     
png .Save(@"C:\caminho-da-imagem.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Note que isto vai fazer com que as partes sem fundo do PNG fiquem com a cor **preto** na nova imagem.

Para evitar isso, será necessário trabalhar em cima da imagem original.

O código abaixo, cria uma instância de **`Bitmap`** com as dimensões da imagem original, seta a resolução conforme a imagem original e depois cria uma instância de `Graphics` com o método [**`Graphics.FromImage`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx).

Com a instância de `Graphics` toda a superfície é pintada de branco (obviamente você pode fazer isso com qualquer cor) usando o método [**`Graphics.Clear`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) e depois a imagem original é "desenhada" em cima da nova usando o método [**`DrawImageUnscaled`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0tzkb5(v=vs.110).aspx), o segundo e terceiro parâmetro são referentes à posição em que a imagem vai ser desenhada, como queremos uma imagem completamente igual, usamos a posição (0, 0).

```
Image png = Image.FromFile(@"C:\caminho-da-imagem.png");
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(png.Width, png.Height)) 
{
    bitmap.SetResolution(png.HorizontalResolution, png.VerticalResolution);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) 
    {
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(png, 0, 0);
    }

    bitmap.Save(@"C:\caminho-nova-imagem.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

---

Fiz um teste usando esta imagem aqui

[image: Stack Overflow Logo]

<sup>[Clique na imagem (ou aqui) para ver a falta de *background*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpPcF.png)</sup>

O primeiro código, gerou esta imagem

[image: Stack Overflow Logo]

O segundo código, gerou esta imagem

[image: Stack Overflow Logo]

Comment: Vale mencionar a fonte original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6513661/1845714

Comment: @OnoSendai mas essa não é a fonte original

Answer (score 3):

Conforme a MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/twss4wb0(v=vs.90).aspx

Carrega a imagem:

```
System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\imagem-especifica.png");
```

Salva como JPEG:

```
image1.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Salva como GIF:

```
image1.Save(@"C:\test.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Salva como PNG:

```
image1.Save(@"C:\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

---

### Extra

Supondo que você esteja manipulando a imagem, por exemplo queira redimensionar ou ajustar a qualidade, então é provavel que irá usar `Bitmap`, neste caso use o `using` para evitar que o arquivo "fique aberto", por exemplo:

```
System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\imagem-especifica.png");

using(var bmp = new Bitmap(image1))
{
    //Faz algo aqui
}

//Salva
image1.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```